# Get response from wechatweb URL

Tags: c#, json, httpresponse, wechat

I want to handle the response from the below WeChat URL in my C# App:-

```
https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/oauth2/authorize?appid=APPID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=SCOPE&state=STATE#wechat_redirect
```

As mentioned in URL I want to get "code" value as JSON response. 
I have no idea how I will get the response.
how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a great tutorial on the MSDN page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Also have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input,although I was expecting someone who have worked in WeChat integration. Anyway thanks for the guide.

Comment: Please check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers that gives guidance on link-only answers. Additionally providing such a generic answer to question that already asked many times is simply useless for the site. Sometimes answering specific version of the question may be appropriate, but posting generic links instead of voting/flagging as duplicate is not a good choice.

Comment: Thank you Alexei. I would normally have written this "answer" as a comment, but my low reputation doesn't allow me to.
Would that be okay?